# R: How to evaluate rationalfit model

Tags: r, regression, model-evaluation

I intend to use rationalfit function in r to fit a rational model to my data. I was wondering to know how I can evaluate the created model. When I use summary() command on the model, it gives nothing. Also, when I get residuals using residuals() command and plot it, it shows a weird figure. I used the following commands to create model and plot residuals.

```
fit = rationalfit(x, z, d1=4, d2=4)
p1 <- fit$p1; p2 <- fit$p2
zs <- polyval(p1,x) / polyval(p2,x)
plot(x, z, type="l", col="blue", ylim=c(0, 40.0))
points(x, Re(zs), col="red") # max(abs(z-zs), na.rm=TRUE) < 1e-6
grid()


res = residuals(fit)
plot(x, res)
abline(0, 0)
```

x and z are numeric vectors and their scatter plot is shown in the following.

[image]

Also, this is the residual plot.

[image]

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What is `rationalfit` supposed to do?  What assumptions does it make, what model does it adopt, and what procedure does it use?

Comment: It fits a rational function like this to the data: =(_0+_1 +_2 ^2+_3 ^3+_4 ^4)/(1+_1 +_2 ^2+_3 ^3+_4 ^4 )